# Запуск git от имени другого пользователя

Tags: linux, git, visual-studio-code

Использую vscode, через remote-ssh подключаюсь к хосту.

В файле `/root/.bashrc` добавил `alias git='sudo -u user git'`. Выполняя команду `git` из терминала vscode под рутом, ожидаемо гит выполняется от пользователя.

Однако  расширение vscode:git выполняя команду `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` отдает ошибку

> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/...'

Можно ли как нибудь заставить расширение работать от другого пользователя?

P.S. Кроме `git config --global --add safe.directory /...`

Comment: Не выполняйте команды git под рутом.

Comment: Вообще ничего не выполняйте под рутом, кроме команд для обслуживания системы

Comment: У хоста на доступ через ssh только у рута есть, и дабы не выполнять git от него такие танцы с бубном, тк конкурировать или добавлять других пользователей не могу (

Comment: Если у вас есть ssh-доступ к руту, то вам ничего не должно мешать сделать ssh-доступ для обычного пользователя

Comment: А фраза «добавлять других пользователей не могу» противоречит тексту вопроса — кто ж тогда добавил пользователя user, которые используется в упомянутой вами команде «sudo -u user git»? И что мешает подключиться к этому самому user через ssh, особенно если у вас есть root-доступ?

Comment: @andreymal тот кто настраивал хост и добавил user

Comment: Если у вас есть root-доступ, значит вы тоже можете перенастроить хост под свои нужды

Comment: @andreymal Если бы это был мой хост то да, а так выходит ситуация, что могу, но нельзя

Comment: user обычный пользователь или системный вроде www-data ?

Comment: @eri обычный созданный

Comment: ну так логинься тогда им

Comment: Запустите VS Code от имени пользователя `user`. Тогда все операции с репозиторием будут вестись от имени пользователя `user` и вам не потребуется вводить алиасы.